# Unable to place mat-grid-list and mat-list inside mat-dialog-content

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Update**:
stackbliz https://angular-2wqf4b.stackblitz.io

---

I am building a comparison screen, where we can compare two items. I am trying to display those two items as two `mat-cards` inside `mat-grid-list`. Both the items further have a list of attributes to be compared which I'm trying to put inside a `mat-list` using `*ngFor`.

My problem is that `dialog` is not displaying full size with my data. If I put static content e.g. some text inside any tag e.g. `<p>` the `dialog` gets auto-adjusted and becomes full size as shown in the official site [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

If I don't give any custom `CSS` my `dialog` looks like this:

[image]

And if I put below custom `CSS`(**I have tried putting this `CSS` at different elements, but couldn't get satisfying results**):

```
mat-grid-list {
   min-height: 80vh;
   width: 88vw;
}
```

The `dialog` looks like this(**I have inspected the items to show they are going beyond the `dialog` and I'm unable to scroll up to see the top elements of the list**):
[image]

Below is the HTML of my `dialog`. I'm ready to change the internal elements of the dialog as long as they appear well inside the `dialog`.

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Compare</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography"> 
    <mat-grid-list  cols="2">
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-card class="example-card">
              <mat-card-header>
                <img mat-card-avatar [src]="item.image" alt="item.name">
                <mat-card-title>{{item.name}}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle>display discription</mat-card-subtitle>
              </mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-content>
               <mat-list>
                  <h3 mat-subheader>Amenities</h3>
                  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let attribute of item.attributes">
                    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>folder</mat-icon>
                    <h4 mat-line>{{attribute.name}}</h4>
                  </mat-list-item>
                  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                  <h3 mat-subheader>Activities</h3>
                  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let activity of item.activities">
                    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>note</mat-icon>
                    <h4 mat-line>{{activity.name}}</h4>
                  </mat-list-item>
                </mat-list>
              </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-card class="example-card">
              <mat-card-header>
                <!-- <img mat-card-avatar [src]="item.image" alt="itmem.name"> -->
                <mat-card-title>{{item.name}}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle>display discription</mat-card-subtitle>
              </mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-content>
              </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-grid-tile> 
    </mat-grid-list> 
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: can you try creating a sample demo on stackblitz

Comment: sure, working on it.

Comment: @Allabakash, updated the question with the link: https://angular-2wqf4b.stackblitz.io

Comment: do they need to be shown side by side ? or top and bottom ?

Comment: Side by side, in my example, I have populated only one side as of now... you can assume the second one.

Answer (score 0):

For showing dialog full screen you need to set the height and width of the dialog like below.

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, {
      width: '120%',
      height: '100%'
    });
```

and for showing the div's side by side ,

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="1:2">
```

Here is the demo - https://angular-2wqf4b-hasjzk.stackblitz.io/

code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wqf4b-hasjzk

Hope this helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. But, I have tried it before and mentioned in the question as well. Your answer is actually my second screenshot. I still can't see the top elements. One thing I have noticed is that the `mat-dialog-actions`  is actually not at the bottom of the dialog, which might be pushing the content towards the top. I'm working on that for now.

Comment: I'm able to scroll in the demo i have attached and alignment looks fine , I have attached the screenshot, So that is not you expected ?

Comment: That's close but, not UX friendly. You see, on a large screen, it's viewable. But, on the smaller screens, it's not even scrollable.